# How to dump XMMATRIX member value?

Tags: directx, directxmath

Is there a any good way to dump XMMATRIX and XMVECTOR ?

```
XMMATRIX mx = XMMatrixScaling(...) * XMMatrixTranslation(...);

DumpMatrix(mx); // printf the 4x4 matrix member
```

I want `DumpMatrix` like function.

I checked `DirectMath.h`. And found

```
typedef __m128 XMVECTOR;
```

How to extract `(x, y, z, w)` from __m128 ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

DirectX Math library design doesn't allow direct access to `XMMATRIX` and `XMVECTOR` members. It is likely because they store values in special [SIMD data types](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ayeb3ayc.aspx).

To read the components of an `XMVECTOR` you can use [`XMVectorGet*` acces functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee415582%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), for example:

```
XMVECTOR V;
float x = XMVectorGetX(V);
float w;
XMVectorGetWPtr(&w, V);
```

or [`XMStore*` functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee415635%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to store it into a `XMFLOAT4`, which has scalar members with direct access:

```
XMVECTOR vPosition;
XMFLOAT4 fPosition;
XMStoreFloat4(&fPosition, vPosition);
float x = fPosition.x;
```

`XMMATRIX` you can store into a `XMFLOAT4X4`:

```
XMMATRIX mtxView;
XMFLOAT4X4 fView;
XMStoreFloat4x4(&fView, mtxView);
float fView_11 = fView._11;
```

There are also [Load functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee415589%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to make the opposite: write to `XMVECTOR` and `XMMATRIX`.

For further information, refer to [DirectXMath Programming Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee415574%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Happy coding!

Comment: Thank you. I'm newcomer to Win32 and DirectX. The architecture of D3D11 is very interesting.

Comment: Just to expand on this a bit, you can also use the `XMVectorGet` functions to access `XMMATRIX` values: `XMMATRIX m = XMMatrixIdentity(); float r2c2 = XMVectorGetZ(m.r[2]);` (using 0-based indicies). I believe `XMMATRIX` provides public access to its 4 row vectors for just this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment the answer, but i believe the correct code for XMMATRIX is:

```
XMMATRIX mtxView;
XMFLOAT4X4 fView;
XMStoreFloat4x4(&fView, mtxView);
float fView_11 = fView._11;
```

so that you can access the matrix member values using the newly created XMFLOAT4X4

Comment: You are correct, there were several typos. I fixed my answer. Thank you.